# Pseudo-selector combination with nth-child

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to target child elements with 2 combined pseudo-classes: *not* and *nth-child*, to return the even children of my elements **after** having excluded *span*:

```
<div>Will have a left margin</div>
<div></div>
<p>Will have a left margin</p>
<p></p>
<span></span>
<div>Will have a left margin</div>
<div></div>
```

So I tried:

```
#someItem >:not(span):nth-child(even) {
    margin-left: 8px;
}
```

But I obtain that (basically the *nth-child* pseudo-class ignores the *not* selector):

```
<div>Has a left margin</div>
<div></div>
<p>Has a left margin</p>
<p></p>
<span></span>
<div></div>
<div>Has a left margin</div>
```

So I thought about writing it this way (with a general sibling selector), to have the *nth-child* affecting the previously filtered list:

```
#someItem >:not(span) ~:nth-child(even) {
    margin-left: 8px;
}
```

But still out of luck.

Is there some way to make the *nth-child* selector work on an element list from which the *span* elements have been removed? (in pure CSS)

Comment: use `nth-of-type`

Comment: Ah not bad. My elements are not necesarly all div as in my simplified example, but from another answer, using .someClass:nth-child could be OK... Only issue is that I'm using React + JSS, so the classnames are generated... But I'll sort something out.

Comment: if they aren't all divs you cannot do it even with classes (I added another duplicate)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Wow... that sucks. Thanks for the link, my question is indeed somewhat a duplicate. Hard to address with JSS/React technologies. Happily there's a CSS4 proposal for that.